# How do I align this header and body properly?

Tags: minipage, two-column, alignment

The effect I'd like to achieve is:

```
Header: Here's some more text
        that's just here to
        illustrate what I mean. It
        needs to be a bit longer to
        show it properly. That
        should do it.
```

My first thought was to do this with a minipage, but since the width of the page is variable I couldn't get very far. What I'm trying to construct is an environment of two parameters, where #1 is a sort of header that sits off to the left, and a main body of text, #2, next to it, that fills the rest of the width, but then after the line-break "stays in its lane", i.e. is left aligned with the start of #2.

I'm almost certain something like this must exist, but I've searched around for some time and I can't find anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In LaTeX nomenclature a header is at the top of a page (above the text area).  As a list or trivlist, you would call it a lable and reset \labelwidth to match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hanging indentation.

If you need “go to a new line” inside `headedpar`, use `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newenvironment{headedpar}[1]{%
  \par
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1: }
  \hangindent=\dimen0 \hangafter=1
  \noindent #1: \ignorespaces
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{headedpar}{Header}
\lipsum[2][1-5]
\end{headedpar}

\begin{headedpar}{Longer header}
\lipsum[3][1-5]
\end{headedpar}

\lipsum[4][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe you want to add vertical space around such paragraphs. Changing the definition into

```
\newenvironment{headedpar}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1: }
  \hangindent=\dimen0 \hangafter=1
  \noindent #1: \ignorespaces
}{\par\addvspace{\topsep}}
```

will produce the following.

[image]

Comment: If multiple paragraphs are needed in the environment `headedpar`, how to solve the indentation problem of the rest paragraphs except the first one?

Comment: @Stephen I don't think this fits in the description. Using ``\\`` would do better than a “new paragraph”.

Comment: OK, but I'm still curious about whether there is a method that is compatible with "new paragraph" case.

Comment: @Stephen One could use `\everypar` for that job.

Comment: @Stephen - If more than one paragraph has to "hang" from the header line, the `\parbox` approach provided in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/685556/5001) will let you accomplish your formatting objective.

Answer (score 5):

For example, you can define the macro `\head` and the text is finalized by `\ehead`. The macro reads the first parameter separated by column, sets it to the box 0, measures the width of the box and uses it as `\leftskip` for given paragraph.

```
\def\head#1:#2\ehead{\par
   {\setbox0=\hbox{#1: }
    \leftskip=\wd0 \rightskip=0pt plus1fil
    \noindent\llap{\box0}\ignorespaces #2
    \par
}}

\head Header: Here's some more text
        that's just here to
        illustrate what I mean. It
        needs to be a bit longer to
        show it properly. That
        should do it.
\ehead
```

If you want to justify the paragraph, i.e. no ragged right (like in egreg's answer), simply don't set `\rightskip` register. Note, that you can use more paragraph in the `\head`...`\ehead` environment.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that "Header" starts at the left-hand edge of the text block. If you don't want this behavior, simply remove the instructions `\par\noindent` that are currently before `#1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\twoparts[2]{%
   \par\noindent #1:\space%
   \parbox[t]{4cm}{\raggedright #2}\par}
  
\begin{document}

\twoparts{Header}{Here's some more text that's just here to 
  illustrate what I mean. It needs to be a bit longer to 
  show it properly. That should do it.}

\end{document}
```